# Infinite scroll not triggered automatically | How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I want to use infinite scroll option of [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/#loading-class-option) plugin in my Django project. I use next code but plugin don't work correctly. When I go at the end of the document, I want automatically trigger the plugin. But right now plugin works only when I change the size of browser. Where is my mistake, I am little bit confused.

**scripts:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/shortcuts/infinite.min.js">
```

Django render me next html:

```
<ol class="infinite-container">
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
  <li class="infinite-item"></li>
</ol>

<div class="loading">
  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page=2"></a>

<script>
  var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
      $('.loading').show();
    },
    onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
      $('.loading').hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason. My `infinite-container` element was in div block which had `overflow: auto;` style. When I remove this style plugin triggered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine,, but the way you include script files is wrong, see if that is your issue, replace this code >

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js">
```

with script tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

test the demo below

EDIT: if you need to trigger it from bottom earlier, use offset with negative value

```js
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
  element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
  offset: -200,
  onBeforePageLoad: function() {
    $('.loading').show();
    console.log('before pageLoad ajax');
  },
  onAfterPageLoad: function($items) {
    $('.loading').hide();
    console.log('after pageLoad ajax');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/shortcuts/infinite.min.js"></script>
<ol class="infinite-container">
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
  <li class="infinite-item">Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</li>
</ol>

<div class="loading">
  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Loading
</div>

<a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page=2"></a>
```

Comment: Well, It's my fault. In post I make mistake I use script, not link. So the problem not from that. Do you have any other ideas? As I said plugin works only when I change browser size. When I go at the end of the document, I want automatically trigger the plugin. So strange.

Comment: It seems to me I need to add `offset` option but I don't know how to make it correctly. http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/

Comment: oh,, you can define it as number (px from the buttom) or %, for example: `'offset': 150`

Comment: I tried different values, but plugin don't work as I expected. For example any % between 10-50 don't react. When I use 60-90% for example it load me all page. User don't even notice loading icon. In this case there are no stepwise loading.

Comment: where is your icon positioned on the page? and when would you like ajax to be triggered?

Comment: I set icon in `<div class="loading"></div>`. You can see it in my code. When I go at the end of the document (at the end of the page), I want automatically trigger the plugin.

Comment: By default this plugin use `offset="bottom-in-view"`. I set this code: `offset: function() { console.log("OFFSET"); return this.context.innerHeight() - this.adapter.outerHeight() },` I notice when page load this function called twice.

Comment: did you see my edited answer,, you can just put negative val in offset, try if that works